# How to print full screen using shortcut in email without using print option

Tags: windows, macos

When a user book a ticket the confirmation mail will be sent to a client. The client can take printout using the print option available in Email no issue with it. The issue is when user press CTRL + P to print the email, only selected screen is printing with cut-off edges.

Please, anyone, help me to print full email body using the shortcut.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqH4U.png)

Comment: Hi ! please help me on this

Comment: How are you generating the confirmation email? Is this common to all email clients, or just one? Is it just Ctrl+P that doesn't work? Does File -> Print work? Does changing the destination printer type change anything? Can you give us a cut-down example of the email?

Comment: Confirmation mail is common to all clients, If client presses Print option available on th Email it will print. If client press Ctrl + P only selected screen is printing  and edges are cutting. please find the attached screen shot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqH4U.png

Comment: "email client" means Outlook vs Gmail vs ... whatever. Perhaps you could answer that question first? You've also not answered the "how are you generating the email" question -- is it text-only? is it hand-crafted HTML? Are you using some kind of templating library? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm not asking these questions to be annoying, incidentally. These are _questions I would be asking myself_ if I had this problem, and needed to narrow it down.